# Относительные пути в Django

Tags: django

Подскажите, как вписать относительные пути в проекте Django? Хочу, чтобы все пути были написаны не жестко, а относительно, включая и БД, сейчас у меня как-то не очень получилось, проект запустил на локалхосте, но админка - выглядит... никак! Не форматирована, без таблиц, один голый HTML и БД создается не в корне проекта, а в корне MySQL. Подскажите, как сделать правильно!

```
    from os import path

#SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
     ('admin', 'ow@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ow@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dev',
        'USER': 'root', 
        'PASSWORD': '', 
        'HOST': '',     
        'PORT': '',     
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

PROJECT_PATH = path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = 'o77777777777777777777777k$'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'site.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'posts',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается так - в `settings.py`

```
from os import path

PROJECT_PATH = path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
```

...

Это конечно не относительный путь, а абсолютный, но он рассчитывается динамически, в зависимости от положения проекта.

Comment: что-то не получается!
вот обновил свой вопрос(добавил код) и хотел бы узнать,что не так делаю.

Comment: Смысл фразы "БД создается не в корне проекта, а в корне MySQL" для меня остаётся загадкой... Чтобы админка была нормально оформлена при запуске не через manage.py runserver нужно [собрать статические файлы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Comment: в корне это где по умолчанию,сохраняются БД,у меня это datadir = /var/lib/mysql
а как создавать БД в папке проекта?
а,по поводу собирать статические файлы - можно разжевать? у меня это первый день работы в Джанго...плиииз!

Comment: Зачем нужно хранить файлы БД в папке проекта, если вы используете СУБД `MySQL` - советую не заморачиваться об этом и оставить их там, где они есть. 

Статические файлы - картинки, js, css и т.п. Они могут быть у каждого приложения свои. В частности админка - это приложение поставляемое с Django и у неё есть свои статические файлы. Cервер запущенный через `manage.py runserver` сам находит эти файлы для остальных нужно их собрать командой `manage.py collectstatic` - они будут собраны в папку STATIC_ROOT оттуда их нужно переместить в одну из папок перечисленных в STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: создал папку STATIC_ROOT,запустил manage.py collectstatic ,появилась подпапка admin,в которой находятся папки css,img,js. Теперь куда мне их кинуть,что с ними делать?

Comment: Нужно создать папку, в которой будут храниться статические файлы, из которй их будет брать веб-сервер (который нужно настроить брать оттуда файлы, естественно). Она должна отличаться от `STATIC_ROOT` и эту папку добавить записью в `STATICFILES_DIRS` например:

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'staticfiles'),
    )

Answer (score 0):

Похоже с теорией у отвечающих слабовато, нужно бы подучить.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

разве начало на слеш это относительное? Взять хотя бы веб сайт '/test/' - это от корня сайта, а вот относительно это 'test'

Решение для примера -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

меняем на

```
STATIC_URL = 'static'
```

p.s. шаблон в начале разработки ложите в media, со статикой могут быть проблемы, она изначально для сервера предназначена.

Comment: Похоже с практикой у отвечающих слабовато...